# Change the colour of a hyperlink on an email address that is rendered in outlook html email

Tags: c#, html, css, hyperlink, outlook

I have some C# code that inserts an email address into a placeholder in a html string (placeholder is in the format %Email%) and then sends this html as an email which is then opened using Outlook.

Basically I want the hyperlink colour to be white rather than the default blue.

I have tried to use CSS but not does not seem to work with the output in Outlook.  I have also tried hard-coding the colour into html but still without luck.  It seems that the default hyperlink colour is overriding the colour I hard-coded.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably too late. Try putting the style on a span tag inside the a tag.

```
<a href="#" style="color: #fff;"><span style="color: #fff;">Link</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inline styles?

```
<a href="#" style="color: #fff;">Link</a>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I have and still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the relevant piece of the template and then separately show how the markup in the email comes though?